# Calculating a total in Power BI for a measure column

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have data in power bi which looks like this:

[image]

The total column is a measure which simply takes on hand qty times average value.
How can I show the total of the "Total" Column as a sum instead of using a calculation of 19491 x 0.74 = 14390.86. The total of the column should look like this:

[image]

Appreciate any help

Comment: Can you paste your data as copiable text?

Comment: I have tried doing this as per the guide lines but it simply wont turn into a table Here is copiable data though:Item Qty on Hand Average Value Total
a  2,048   0.96   1,966.08 
b  2,070   0.98   2,028.60 
c  1,200   0.60   720.00 
d  13,500   0.38   5,130.00 
e  600   0.75   450.00 
f  73   0.76   55.48

Comment: yes thank you very much all sorted finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
total = SUMX('Table', 'Table'[Qty on Hand] * 'Table'[Average Value])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SUM()` function, place the two columns in the table into the function should provide you with the desired result.